# Concatenate several columns as comma-separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The following is a starting point to concatenate several columns to one string where the values are comma separated. If the column entry is empty or NULL no comma should be used:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        Id INT,
        Name1 NVARCHAR(10) ,
        Name2 NVARCHAR(10) ,
        Name3 NVARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT  INTO #Temp
        SELECT  1,
                N'Name1' ,
                NULL ,
                N'Name3'
UNION
        SELECT  2,
                N'Name1' ,
                N'Name2' ,
                N'Name3'
UNION 
        SELECT  3,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                N'Name3'
UNION 
        SELECT  
                4,
                N'' ,
                N'' ,
                N'Name3';

SELECT  Id, STUFF(COALESCE(N',' + Name1, N'') + COALESCE(N',' + Name2, N'')
              + COALESCE(N',' + Name3, N''), 1, 1, '') AS ConcateStuff
FROM    #Temp;
```

The current results are as follows:

```
Id  ConcateStuff
1   Name1,Name3
2   Name1,Name2,Name3
3   Name3
4   ,,Name3
```

Everything work fine for NULL entries but not for empty entries. The last row's result should just be:

```
Name3
```

Is there a simple way to get this to work without using complex nested case statements (ultimately I have to concatenate more than 3 columns).

Comment: plus 1 for sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `NULLIF` you can achieve it.

```
SELECT  Id, STUFF(COALESCE(N',' + NULLIF(Name1, ''), N'') + COALESCE(N',' + NULLIF(Name2, ''), N'')
              + COALESCE(N',' + NULLIF(Name3, ''), N''), 1, 1, '') AS ConcateStuff
FROM    #Temp;
```

**Result**

```
Id  ConcateStuff
-----------------
1   Name1,Name3
2   Name1,Name2,Name3
3   Name3
4   Name3
```